# Change subsequent data based on a particular column value, and only for the duration of the trial in which it occurs

Tags: r

I am trying to do what I think is 'filling forward' for the duration of a trial IF that trial contains a 1 (1 and 0 are the only possible values). Here is an example set of data, where there are some fixations (=1) in the first trial, and none in the second trial:

```
trial      fixation
  1           0
  1           0
  1           1
  1           1
  1           0
  1           0
  1           0
  1           0
  2           0
  2           0
  2           0
  2           0
  2           0
  2           0
```

So, when the function finds the 1 values, it should fill the remainder of the fixation column for *that trial only* with 1s:

```
trial      fixation
  1           0
  1           0
  1           1
  1           1
  1           1
  1           1
  1           1
  1           1
  2           0
  2           0
  2           0
  2           0
  2           0
  2           0
```

Does anyone have any ways to do this (preferably using either `data.table::rleid` or `dplyr`)?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `cummax` on the grouped 'trial'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(trial) %>%
    mutate(fixation = cummax(fixation)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 2
   trial fixation
   <int>    <int>
 1     1        0
 2     1        0
 3     1        1
 4     1        1
 5     1        1
 6     1        1
 7     1        1
 8     1        1
 9     2        0
10     2        0
11     2        0
12     2        0
13     2        0
14     2        0
```

---

As `cummax` is from `base R`, we can also use `base R` methods

```
df1$fixation <-  with(df1, ave(fixation, trial, FUN = cummax))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), fixation = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```